# Error when installing Gon WordPress theme

Tags: wordpress

I find Gon WordPress theme on the internet and do as a guide. When I click Import button, errors occurred[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This's just a warning from PHP for debugging purpose. You can hide it if you want, but you should fix until there's no warning left.

On your production, first you should hide this info by change `WP_DEBUG` to `false` in `wp-config.php` or replace that line with below code:

```
ini_set('display_errors','Off');
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL );
define('WP_DEBUG', false);
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);
```

If this is your testing environment, you should contact theme provider to fix this issue. May be PHP version incompatible or the error that theme's author not seen this before.

Comment: Hi Tuan, in `wp-config.php` defaulted `define( 'WP_DEBUG', false );`

Comment: Edited my answer, can you test again?

Comment: Thanks, Tuan! How to fix errors? I don't fix it because I don't know code. Can you give me an example

Comment: As I said, you should contact this theme's author to ask them how to fix this error. Hide the PHP warning is not recommended.